# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key in object

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, primary-key

I inherited a project and I'm running into a SQL error that I'm not sure how to fix.

On an eCommerce site, the code is inserting order shipping info into another database table.

Here's the code that is inserting the info into the table:

```cs
string sql = "INSERT INTO AC_Shipping_Addresses   
(pk_OrderID, FullName, Company, Address1, Address2, City, Province, PostalCode, CountryCode, Phone, Email, ShipMethod, Charge_Freight, Charge_Subtotal)  
VALUES (" + _Order.OrderNumber;
sql += ", '" + _Order.Shipments[0].ShipToFullName.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
if (_Order.Shipments[0].ShipToCompany == "")
{
  sql += ", '" + _Order.Shipments[0].ShipToFullName.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
}
else
{
  sql += ", '" + _Order.Shipments[0].ShipToCompany.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
}
sql += ", '" + _Order.Shipments[0].Address.Address1.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
sql += ", '" + _Order.Shipments[0].Address.Address2.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
sql += ", '" + _Order.Shipments[0].Address.City.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
sql += ", '" + _Order.Shipments[0].Address.Province.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
sql += ", '" + _Order.Shipments[0].Address.PostalCode.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
sql += ", '" + _Order.Shipments[0].Address.Country.Name.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
sql += ", '" + _Order.Shipments[0].Address.Phone.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
if (_Order.Shipments[0].ShipToEmail == "")
{
  sql += ",'" + _Order.BillToEmail.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
}
else
{
  sql += ",'" + _Order.Shipments[0].ShipToEmail.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
}
sql += ", '" + _Order.Shipments[0].ShipMethod.Name.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
sql += ", " + shippingAmount;
sql += ", " + _Order.ProductSubtotal.ToString() + ")";
bll.dbUpdate(sql);
```

It is working correctly, but it is also outputting the following SQL error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_AC_Shipping_Addresses'. Cannot insert
> duplicate key in object 'dbo.AC_Shipping_Addresses'. The duplicate key value
> is (165863).

From reading similar questions, it seems that I should declare the ID in the statement.

Is that correct? How would I adjust the code to fix this issue?

Comment: **[Possible SQL Injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)**

Comment: Step 1) Find out what the value of `sql` is prior to running. Step 0) Change to using bind values for the query instead of concatenation. Google "SQL Injection" for reason why.

Comment: What is the value you're passing to the primary key (presumably "pk_OrderID")? You can set it up to auto increment, and then there should never be a problem with duplicating the value - the DB will take care of that. If you need to specify a value yourself, you'll need to write code to determine what the max value for that field is, and then increment that.

Comment: what is your unique key field? looks like your OrderNumber is duplicate, you may already have the order# 165863 in your table and you are trying to insert a duplciate

Comment: If the PK value exists already then you can merely update it or you'll have to delete the prior value before inserting a new one: `string sql = "DELETE FROM AC_Shipping_Addresses where pk_OrderID = " + _Order.OrderNumber;`

Comment: If you have a column named "ID" or such that is not shown in the qurery, that's fine as long as it is set up to autoincrement - but it's probably not, or you shouldn't get that err msg. Also, you would be better off writing an easier-on-the-eye query and using params. As the lad of nine years hence inferred, you're leaving your database open to sql injection attacks if you simply plop in user-entered values.

Comment: It is taking the Order ID and inserting that into pk_OrderID, so that should never be a duplicate. That is the only unique value. Is there an easy way to check the _Order.OrderNumber against a possible duplicate pk_OrderID value first before inserting?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon there isn't an ID column. The available column names are all in the insert statement. Could you possibly help me convert the statement to avoid SQL injection?

Comment: ... *my god, its full of*  "'+"''" '"" + "''" !

Comment: At the very least show us the definition of PK_AC_Shipping_Addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `pk_OrderID` is the PK of `AC_Shipping_Addresses`

And you are trying to insert a duplicate via the `_Order.OrderNumber`?

Do a

```sql
select * from AC_Shipping_Addresses where pk_OrderID = 165863;
```

or `select count(*)` ....

Pretty sure you will get a row returned.

It is telling you that you are already using `pk_OrderID = 165863` and cannot have another row with that value.

if you want to not insert if there is a row

```sql
insert into table (pk, value) 
select 11 as pk, 'val' as value 
where not exists (select 1 from table where pk = 11)
```

Comment: I'm trying to add some code to check for the value first now. Does this look like it would be correct?: string exists = "SELECT 1 from AC_Shipping_Addresses where pk_OrderID = " _Order.OrderNumber;
            if (exists > 0)
            {
              // already exists
            } else {
              // insert order data

Comment: Yes in theory that would work.  But I add something I like better.

Comment: this is not a good answer where developer determines primary column as identity auto increment column !!  this is a escape code not solution :)

Answer (score 32):

I was getting the same error on a restored database when I tried to insert a new record using the EntityFramework. It turned out that the Indentity/Seed was screwing things up.

Using a reseed command fixed it.

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[Prices]', RESEED, 4747030);GO
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the value you're passing to the primary key (presumably "pk_OrderID")? You can set it up to auto increment, and then there should never be a problem with duplicating the value - the DB will take care of that. If you need to specify a value yourself, you'll need to write code to determine what the max value for that field is, and then increment that.

If you have a column named "ID" or such that is not shown in the query, that's fine as long as it is set up to autoincrement - but it's probably not, or you shouldn't get that err msg. Also, you would be better off writing an easier-on-the-eye query and using params. As the lad of nine years hence inferred, you're leaving your database open to SQL injection attacks if you simply plop in user-entered values. For example, you could have a method like this:

```
internal static int GetItemIDForUnitAndItemCode(string qry, string unit, string itemCode)
{
    int itemId;
    using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ReportRunnerConstsAndUtils.CPSConnStr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, sqlConn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Unit", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Value = unit;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ItemCode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Value = itemCode;
            sqlConn.Open();
            itemId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        }
    }
    return itemId;
}
```

...that is called like so:

```
int itemId = SQLDBHelper.GetItemIDForUnitAndItemCode(GetItemIDForUnitAndItemCodeQuery, _unit, itemCode);
```

You don't have to, but I store the query separately:

```
public static readonly String GetItemIDForUnitAndItemCodeQuery = "SELECT PoisonToe FROM Platypi WHERE Unit = @Unit AND ItemCode = @ItemCode";
```

You can verify that you're not about to insert an already-existing value by (pseudocode):

```
bool alreadyExists = IDAlreadyExists(query, value) > 0;
```

The query is something like "SELECT COUNT FROM TABLE WHERE BLA = @CANDIDATEIDVAL" and the value is the ID you're potentially about to insert:

```
if (alreadyExists) // keep inc'ing and checking until false, then use that id value
```

Justin wants to know if this will work:

```
string exists = "SELECT 1 from AC_Shipping_Addresses where pk_OrderID = " _Order.OrderNumber; if (exists > 0)...
```

What seems would work to me is:

```
string existsQuery = string.format("SELECT 1 from AC_Shipping_Addresses where pk_OrderID = {0}", _Order.OrderNumber); 
// Or, better yet:
string existsQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) from AC_Shipping_Addresses where pk_OrderID = @OrderNumber"; 
// Now run that query after applying a value to the OrderNumber query param (use code similar to that above); then, if the result is > 0, there is such a record.
```

Comment: It is taking the Order ID (_Order.OrderNumber) and inserting that into pk_OrderID. Is there an easy way to check the _Order.OrderNumber against a possible duplicate pk_OrderID value first before inserting?

Comment: Yes, check for that value in the table you're about to insert into; if it exists, inc the number. You might need to keep checking until you find a number that doesn't already exist.

Comment: To check for the value, would this be the correct statement? 

    bool alreadyExists = IDAlreadyExists(SELECT COUNT(*) from AC_Shipping_Addresses where pk_OrderID = _Order.OrderNumber, _Order.OrderNumber) > 0;

Comment: This should be enough:
"SELECT COUNT(*) from AC_Shipping_Addresses where pk_OrderID = _Order.OrderNumber"

Comment: Sorry, I've never written an if/else statement with SQL queries before. Would that be like this? if ("SELECT COUNT(*) from AC_Shipping_Addresses where pk_OrderID = _Order.OrderNumber" != 0) {  //do insert } Will the statement return 0 or NULL if there isn't a matching value?

Comment: No, just what I wrote should be enough. See Frisbee's answer; you can just select count instead of everything (*), though.

Comment: Does this look correct? string exists = "SELECT 1 from AC_Shipping_Addresses where pk_OrderID = " _Order.OrderNumber;
            if (exists > 0)
            {
              // already exists
            } else {
              // insert order data

Comment: Justin, I'll answer this latest in an amendment/appendage to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not OP's answer but as this was the first question that popped up for me in google, Id also like to add that users searching for this might need to reseed their table, which was the case for me

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT(tablename)
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent inserting a record that exist already. I'd check if the ID value exists in the database. For the example of a Table created with an IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Persons] (    
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    LastName VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    FirstName VARCHAR(40)
);
```

When JANE DOE and JOE BROWN already exist in the database.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Persons] OFF;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Persons] (FirstName,LastName)
VALUES ('JANE','DOE'); 
INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName,LastName) 
VALUES ('JOE','BROWN');
```

**DATABASE OUTPUT of TABLE [dbo].[Persons] will be:**

```
ID    LastName   FirstName
1     DOE        Jane
2     BROWN      JOE
```

I'd check if i should update an existing record or insert a new one. As the following JAVA example:

```
int NewID = 1;
boolean IdAlreadyExist = false;
// Using SQL database connection
// STEP 1: Set property
System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true");
// STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
// STEP 3: Open a connection
try (Connection conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER,pwd) {
    conn1.setAutoCommit(true);
    String Select = "select * from Persons where  ID = " + ID;
    Statement st1 = conn1.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs1 = st1.executeQuery(Select);
    // iterate through the java resultset
    while (rs1.next()) {
        int ID = rs1.getInt("ID");
        if (NewID==ID) {
            IdAlreadyExist = true;
        }

    }
    conn1.close();
} catch (SQLException e1) {
    System.out.println(e1);
}
if (IdAlreadyExist==false) {
    //Insert new record code here
} else {
    //Update existing record code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share my experience through this error.

I had requirement to move schema and data from local in house SQL server to azure SQL server.

I tried to achieve this by following couple of approaches.

1. I tried bacpac from in house server to azure.
2. Also used the one of the features of the SSMS like Tasks > Deploy database to Microsoft Azure SQL database.
3. Used Microsoft Data Migration Assistant tool as well.

Problem was, when a script was executing, somehow a table, which is facing this already having id problem, is having records automatically added, it could be because of the cursor or any unique key applied (Not sure why it was happening).

So, in order to resolve this, you have to check whether records are there or not before executing this query or not.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several things causing this and it somewhat depends on what you have set up in your database.

First, you could be using a PK in the table that is also an FK to another table making the relationship 1-1. IN this case you may need to do an update rather than an insert. If you really can have only one address record for an order this may be what is happening.

Next you could be using some sort of manual process to determine the id ahead of time. The trouble with those manual processes is that they can create race conditions where two records gab the same last id and increment it by one and then the second one can;t insert.

Third, you query as it is sent to the database may be creating two records. To determine if this is the case, Run Profiler to see exactly what SQL code you are sending and if ti is a select instead of a values clause, then run the select and see if you have due to the joins gotten some records to be duplicated. IN any even when you are creating code on the fly like this the first troubleshooting step is ALWAYS to run Profiler and see if what got sent was what you expected to be sent.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure if your table doesn't already have rows whose Primary Key values are same as the the Primary Key Id in your Query.