# SonarQube - Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ce_activity'

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube

Currently, we are using SonarQube 8.8.

Our Azure DevOps builds that use SonarQube have been running fine for awhile with no issues. Recently our builds have been hanging on the “publish quality gate result” step. When looking at the logs we found that we receive this error:

```
Error updating database. Cause: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'pk_ce_activity'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ce_activity'. The duplicate key value is ....
```

It looks like their is something in our pipeline that is trying to use a uuid that is already in our Microsoft SQL Server database.

Any ideas on how to mitigate this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a SQL server database issue.

You can reference the following articles to try solving the issue:

- https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000016425
- [Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key in object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36043439/violation-of-primary-key-constraint-cannot-insert-duplicate-key-in-object)